# webpackでのTweenMax、EasePackの使い方（typescriptを使用）

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

TimelineMaxやTweenLiteは使えているのですが、同じようにしてもTweenMaxが使えません。

webpack.config.jsではresolveのaliasで以下のように設定しています。

```
alias: {
    TweenLite: 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite.js',
    TweenMax: 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenMax.js',
    TimelineLite: 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineLite.js',
    TimelineMax: 'gsap/src/uncompressed/TimelineMax.js',
    EasePack: 'gsap/src/uncompressed/easing/EasePack.js',
    ScrollToPlugin: 'gsap/src/uncompressed/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.js'
},
```

tsファイルでは以下のようにimportしています。

```
import TweenMax = require('TweenMax');
```

ただ、`console.log(TweenMax)`としても空のobjectが返ってきており、
当然`TweenMax.to()`などはそんなfunctionは存在しないとerrorがでます。

https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS/issues/91#issuecomment-148332900
この人と同じように以下のようにしても空のobjectが返ってくることに変化なく。。

```
plugins: [ 
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({TweenMax: "TweenMax"})
]
```

読み込んでいるGSAPのnpm packageは 1.18.2です。
webpackは1.12.14
typescriptは1.8.7

webpackでのTweenMaxの使用方法ご教示いただければ幸いです。

あわせて、
EasePackはTweenMaxがimportできれば使えると思っていますがまちがいないでしょうか？
また、ScrollToPluginも使用したいのですが、これはどのようにimportすればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 当時と状況も変わり自己解決しました。
ありがとうございました。

Comment: @tadasi さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。解決に至った情報を分かる範囲で一緒に記載しておいてもらえると、同じ問題で困った人がいた場合の助けになると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決した内容ですが、gsapがwebpackに対応したためです
こちらを参照してください。
[Best way to use GSAP with Webpack](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16676-best-way-to-use-gsap-with-webpack/?tab=comments#comment-73795)

私の方法が悪いのかもしれませんがScrollToPluginのみimportができないのでこのコメントのようにaliasを設定しています。
[GSAP & NPM/Webpack `import` for ScrollToPlugin](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/14873-gsap-npmwebpack-import-for-scrolltoplugin/?tab=comments#comment-63993)